# How to avoid two same events from getting called simultaneously in two different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, socket.io

I have an Activity in which there is a tab layout in which i am having two different Fragments. I am using viewpager to move into these fragments.

```
 public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new MainActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Dashboard(), "Dashboard");
        adapter.addFragment(new Buysell(), "Buy/Sell");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

In both fragments i am using some socket.io events which are same.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    AppController app = (AppController) 
    getActivity().getApplication();
    mSocket = app.getSocket();

    mSocket.on("inr_balance_data", inrBalanceData);
    mSocket.on("order_notify", server_Response_Buy);

}
```

In both fragments event "order_notify" is same. So the problem which i am facing is when i am emitting some event from one fragment and order_notify  is supposed to listen that event, then the order_notify gets called in both fragments.

I want if i am emitting any event from dashboard fragment then only order_notify which is present in dashboard fragment should gets called.

and when i am emitting any event from buysell fragment then only  order_notify which is present in buysell fragment should gets called.

currently both order_notify gets called irrespective of from which fragment the request has been initiated.

i think we can achieve this by killing the fragment which is not visible.
can we do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following lines:

```
mSocket.on("inr_balance_data", inrBalanceData);
mSocket.on("order_notify", server_Response_Buy);
```

to:

```
mSocket.off("inr_balance_data");
mSocket.off("order_notify");
mSocket.on("inr_balance_data", inrBalanceData);
mSocket.on("order_notify", server_Response_Buy);
```

By doing this you have only one instance of your listener as previous one is terminated which was created in previous fragment.So whenever fragment restarts it will close the previous instance and will create the new instance.

Comment: it helped sir, Thank you so much.